# Show whether $g$ defines a function and if it does, explain whether it's a bijection or not.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show whether $g: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ defines a function and if it does, explain whether it's a bijection or not.

$1) g(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{2m}{3n}$.

Let $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{m}{n}$, then $g(\frac{p}{q})=g(\frac{m}{n})$, so $g$ defines a function. Assume $g(\frac{m_1}{n_1}) = g(\frac{m_2}{n_2}) \Rightarrow \frac{2m_1}{3n_1}=\frac{2m_2}{3n_2} \Rightarrow \frac{m_1}{n_1}=\frac{m_2}{n_2}$, therefore $g$ is injective.

$2) g(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{(m-n)^2}{n^2}$.

Let $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{m}{n}$, then $g(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{(m-n)^2}{n^2} = \frac{m^2-2mn-n^2}{n^2}=\frac{m^2}{n^2}-\frac{2m}{n}-1=\frac{p^2}{q^2}-\frac{2p}{q}-1 = \frac{(p-q)^2}{q^2} = g(\frac{p}{q})$, so $g$ defines a function. Now assume $g(\frac{m_1}{n_1}) = g(\frac{m_2}{n_2})$, then $\frac{m_1^2}{n_1^2}-\frac{2m_1}{n_1}-1 = \frac{m_2^2}{n_2^2}-\frac{2m_2}{n_2}-1 \Rightarrow (\frac{m_1}{n_1}-1)^2 = (\frac{m_2}{n_2}-1)^2 \iff \begin{cases}
      \frac{m_1}{n_1}-1 = \frac{m_2}{n_2}-1 \\
      \frac{m_1}{n_1}-1 = -(\frac{m_2}{n_2}-1) 
\end{cases}
\iff \begin{cases}
      \frac{m_1}{n_1} = \frac{m_2}{n_2} \\
      \frac{m_1}{n_1} = -\frac{m_2}{n_2}+2; \text{in this case} \frac{m_1}{n_1} \neq \frac{m_2}{n_2} \text{, so $g$ is not injective, hence not bijective}  
\end{cases}$

$g(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{m+1}{m}$.
$g(\frac{2}{4}) = \frac{3}{2},$ but $g(\frac{4}{8}) = \frac{5}{4}$, thus $g$ is not a function. therefore, not a bijection.

Are these proofs valid? and how should I show subjectivity in the first problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could show surjectivity by showing that if $\frac pq\in\Bbb Q$ then there is $r\in \Bbb Q$ such that $g(r)=\frac pq$

Comment: I'd write 'then $\frac{2p}{3q} = \frac{2m}{3n}$, so $g$ defines a function' since we don't know if it is a function at this point

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, let $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb Q$, then there is $r = \frac{3p}{2q}$, such that $g(r) = \frac{p}{q}$, so $g$ is surjective?

Comment: yes, since for all $\frac p q \in \Bbb Q$ there is $r=\frac{3p}{2q}\in\Bbb Q$ such that $g(r)=\frac pq$, $g$ is surjective

Comment: 1 does not.    n has to be nonzero.